# Debugging Wordpress Filter for upload mimes

Tags: php, wordpress, mime-types

I am using this filter from the WordPress Codex in my function.php to allow the upload of svg, svgz and dxf files. But with all uploaded test files I have uploaded were rejected by security reasons from WordPress. Is there some more I have to pay attention to in order to get this working?

```
function my_custom_mime_types( $mimes ) {

    // New allowed mime types.
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $mimes['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    $mimes['dxf'] = 'application/dxf';


return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_custom_mime_types' );
```

Comment: is it some new kind of spamming method? i don't like to loose my time

Answer (score 1):

[As of wordpress 4.7.1 this is a fix](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/post/wordpress-4-7-1-svg-upload)

```
// Allow SVG
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', function($data, $file, $filename, 
$mimes) {

  global $wp_version;
  if ( $wp_version !== '4.7.1' ) {
     return $data;
  }

  $filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes );

  return [
      'ext'             => $filetype['ext'],
      'type'            => $filetype['type'],
      'proper_filename' => $data['proper_filename']
  ];

}, 10, 4 );

function cc_mime_types( $mimes ){
  $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  $mimes['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  $mimes['dxf'] = 'application/dxf';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types' );

function fix_svg() {
  echo '<style type="text/css">
    .attachment-266x266, .thumbnail img {
         width: 100% !important;
         height: auto !important;
    }
    </style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'fix_svg' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the code and the reference Aaron!

I took some adaption I could find on codepen so you don't have to change the WP Version manually:

```
    function relationship_options_filter($options, $field, $the_post) {
    $options[‘post_status’] = array(‘publish’);
    return $options;
}
add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/query/key=field_59074524ac92e', 'relationship_options_filter', 10, 3);


// Allow SVG
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', function($data, $file, $filename, $mimes) {

    global $wp_version; if( $wp_version == '4.7' || ( (float) $wp_version < 4.7 ) ) { return $data; }

    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes );

    return [ 'ext' => $filetype['ext'], 'type' => $filetype['type'], 'proper_filename' => $data['proper_filename'] ];

}, 10, 4 );

function cc_mime_types( $mimes ){
  $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  $mimes['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  $mimes['dxf'] = 'image/x-dwg';

  return $mimes;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types' );

function fix_svg() {
  echo '<style type="text/css">
    .attachment-266x266, .thumbnail img {
         width: 100% !important;
         height: auto !important;
    }
    </style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'fix_svg' );
```